# My shuffle card program is only giving me clubs as the suit

Tags: python, shuffle

I have to do a shuffle card deck for a programming class I am taking, and I am really stumped. Most of my code is unnecessary because we are learning functions. I think i have everything correct, but my output is only giving me clubs as the suit.

```
import random

def define_cards():
    rank_string = ("ace","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","jack","queen","king")
    suit_string = ("clubs","diamonds","hearts","spades")
    cards = []
    for suit in range(4):
        for rank in range(13):
            card_string = rank_string[rank] + " of " + suit_string[suit]
            cards.append(card_string)
        return cards

def create_deck(deck):
    for i in range(52):
        deck.append(i)
        return

def shuffle_deck(deck):
    random.shuffle(deck)
    return

def deal_card(deck):
    return deck.pop(0)

deck=[]

deck = define_cards()
shuffle_deck(deck)
print ("The first 10 cards are:")
for i in range(10):
    card = deal_card(deck)
    print (card)
```

The result should be the same, but with randomized suits.
Please help me!!!

Comment: Is `create_deck` functionality same as `deck = range(52)`

Comment: @Brady The best way to create a deck is `itertools.product`. You can read about it if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the define_cards function `return` should be outside the for loop.

Same for create_deck function.

```
def define_cards():
    rank_string = ("ace","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten","jack","queen","king")
    suit_string = ("clubs","diamonds","hearts","spades")
    cards = []
    for suit in range(4):
        for rank in range(13):
            card_string = rank_string[rank] + " of " + suit_string[suit]
            cards.append(card_string)
    return cards
```

Comment: Also, same comment for `create_deck` function.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `create_deck()` is unnecessary - in fact, it's never called!

Comment: You are right @Ken. But just for the sake of debugging I mentioned it.